# Gradle plugin for Android not creating source code folder

Tags: gradle, android-studio

In my Android Studio project, I added the following build type to the build.gradle file:

```
jnidebug.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
jnidebug {
    packageNameSuffix ".jnidebug"
    jniDebuggable true
}
```

The documentation at:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

says:

```
For each Build Type, a new matching sourceSet is created, with a
default location of src/<buildtypename>/
```

But when I resync gradle, the source code folder src/jnidebug never gets created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that for each build type, a *source set* (which is a logical concept/domain object) is created and *configured* with a default location. It doesn't say that a source directory is created. You'll probably have to create the directory yourself. (Android Studio could certainly help with that, so perhaps file a feature request.)